# What are the best practices to migrate to new version of libraries in OSGi environment?

Tags: migration, osgi, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I have the following case: There are some OSGi applications in our environment, which consists of apache-karaf 2.0 and apache-camel 2.4.0. Now we would like to switch our production environment to the latest versions of karaf (2.1.4) and camel (2.6.0). The problem is that we have some package constraints in our old applications, which are incompatible with new version of camel.

Are there any best practices to migrate existing OSGi code to new versions of libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you have two options:

- modify the old applications to use the new bundles
- keep both the old and the new versions. OSGi can handle very nicely several versions of the same bundles / packages. It is actually one of its built features.

Comment: I begin to understand that modularity is really difficult. Although OSGi supports multiple versions of the same library well enough it is necessary to support versions of application endpoints (soap, jms, etc.) too.